# How to make an existing directory (and sub-directories) to be suddenly writable by ROOT ONLY?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, security, chmod

Let's say i have a directory, at:

- `/tmp/uploads/`

And inside got several recursive directories and files created by DIFFERENT USERS before.

So now, suddenly how do i make that above directory to be **writable by root only**?

Which means, the existing whatever users won't be suddenly able to write at all (but read only). So then only `root` will be able to write any further.

---

**Very importantly, i can NOT lose the original ownership *(who owns what)* of the things inside.**

---

Which also means, after all, i am trying to LOCK the directory for security reason.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the difference between a sudden write and a normal one?

Answer (score 5):

Use attributes:

```
chattr -R +i files
```

(as root) will add the `+i` attribute recursively to your folders and files which will prevent ANY alternations. Note that root will also be locked and you would need to unset the `i` manually every time. Ownership and alike will be left unchanged.

Comment: Will this apply recursively please. And how do i 'unset the `i` manually' again? Use `-i` instead? Thanks much!

Comment: The `-R` is for adding it recursively, for unsetting, you guessed correctly, `-i` is the thing to do. Check `man chattr` for a more detailed list of possible attributes. Please also note: if you have `dir1/dir2/` where `dir1` is `+i`, and `dir2` is `-i`, any file can be written to `dir2` (according to the permissions of course)

Answer (score -1):

First change user and group to root

`chown -R root:root /tmp/uploads`

then change permissions so that only root can write

`chmod -R 755 /tmp/uploads`

EDIT:

If you only need to restore files owners, I would save your files and owner in a file (There sure are better ways to do this, but this is the first thing that comes to my mind). Be sure /tmp/old_file_owners doesn't exist before runing the next:

`for i in $(find /tmp/uploads);do ls -ld $i|awk -vf=$i '{if (NF==9) {print $3 ":" $4 " " f}}'>>/tmp/old_file_owners; done`

and when you want to restore your files' owners, just do a

`IFS=$'\n';for i in $(cat /tmp/old_file_owners);do chown $i;done`

If you want to keep original file permissions more info will need to be stored in your file, but you can use the previous as a reference and do your stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks but ... then how do i do when i can revert back the permissions? I mean, since you gonna lose the original owners, how do you later give them the permissions back?

Comment: I updated a bit to my question above. :)

Comment: You didn't specify anything about giving back permissions. They will be able to access the files in read mode, another thing is if you want to revert those files owner back to their original user. In that case you will need to store that information and use it when you want to revert the files owners.

Comment: Thanks, but so then this use-case is impossible, unless i change all to root-owned? :3

Comment: Read Fiximan's answer. That's a great solution without altering ownerships and permissions.